# Set parent over child depth in CSS

Tags: html, css

I need for parent div to be over its children.

I've tried z-index set to -1 and it works for first level, but I need for two or more children depth.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: visible;
}
.one {
  position: relative;
  background: green;
}
.two {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 100px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.three {
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  top: 0;
  left: 150px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <div class="three">    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, class One should be over Two, and Two over Three

thanks

Comment: So, set a different z-index for .three then …?

Comment: set -2 for .three?

Answer (score 1):

Without any z-index value, elements stack in the order that they appear in the DOM (the lowest one down at the same hierarchy level appears on top). Elements with non-static positioning will always appear on top of elements with default static positioning.

Also note that nesting plays a big role. If an element B sits on top of element A, a child element of element A can never be higher than element B.

Try like this

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: visible;
}
.one {
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  z-index:2;
}
.two {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  top: 50px;
  left: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.three {
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  top: 100px;
  left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
</div>
<div class="two">
</div>
<div class="three">
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not work for me. I have menu ul list, so I can't make them siblings. 
I have this menu: [link](http://i.imgur.com/5QzTent.jpg) and on hover I want to child ul move from left to right. I cant do it with css or jquery but child ul always overlap with parent